# Send $scope between controller and Module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I've been stuck on a problem for 4 days. I use a plugin Autocomplete, a directive for AngularJS that uses a script in my html template.

I customized this to add a button that open a modal to add another city if autocomplete find nothing.

```html
<ion-view title=""hide-nav-bar="true" hide-back-button="true" cache-view="false">
  
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/my-custom-template.html" >
              <div class="angucomplete-holder" ng-class="{'angucomplete-dropdown-visible': showDropdown}">
               
                  <div class="angucomplete-row" ng-controller="ShareCtrl" ng-click="selectResult({title: searchStr, originalObject: { name: searchStr, custom: true }})" ng-mouseenter="hoverRow(results.length)" ng-class="{'angucomplete-selected-row': results.length == currentIndex}>

                    <div class="angucomplete-title" ng-click="openModal1()" ng-model="item.cat_id" style="text-align:center;"><i class="ion-plus-circled"></i>  Ajouter un lieu</div>

                </div>
              </div>
</script>

            <div class="item item-input" style="width:100%;overflow: visible;z-index:1000;">

            <div angucomplete-alt id="members"
              placeholder="Lieux"
              pause="100"
              selected-object="item.place"
              remote-url="http://api.formcy.com/v1/search_place?search="
              remote-url-data-field="data"
              title-field="name"
              initial-value="{{nomlieux}}"
              template-url="/my-custom-template.html"
              style="width:95%;"
              /></div>

              
            </div>

 <label class="item item-input">
            <textarea ngMaxlength="180" placeholder="Que vais-je faire cette semaine ?" ng-model="item.title" rows="3"></textarea>
        </label>
       
          <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-model="item.private" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">Name </ion-toggle>

</ion-view>
```

I use a ng-controller to open my modal and add another city but it does not return the scope updated on my controller ShareCtrl.
However, the function openModal1() is in this controller and work perfectly..

My controller

```js
 $scope.add = function(){

   .....code.....

   request.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                      
                            $scope.status = "Votre lieux a été ajouté !";                           
                            $scope.item.place_id = data.place_id;
                            console.log($scope.item);
                            $scope.modalCtrl1.hide();
                            
                            
                        });
 
 };
```

How I can force the $scope.item update without using a service?

Comment: why this absolute hate on services?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid services, you could use events : `$rootScope.$broadcast` (or $emit) and `$scope.$on`.